# SQL Server trigger to auto-populate entire column

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table called `AccuralMonth` with two columns `AccuralID` and `AccuralMonth`.

and another table called `Employee` with a column called `AccuralMonth` too.

I want the function that when a number is entered into the `AccuralMonth` Column of the `AccuralMonth` table, it auto-populates all entries in the `Employee` table.

I have tried using a trigger but it did not work. I got an error when trying to insert value as it would of set a primary key value to null.

```
Create trigger MergeAccurual on [dbo].[AccuralMonth]
after insert,DELETE,UPDATE
as
begin
MERGE [dbo].[Employee] as E
USING [dbo].[AccuralMonth] AS am
ON E.[accrualmonth] = am.[AccuralMonth]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET E.[accrualmonth] = am.[AccuralMonth]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT([accrualmonth]) VALUES(am.[AccuralMonth]);

end
```

Any Ideas? Or even a better way to implement a way to set all values in `AccuralMonth` in `Employees` to a certain value as I do realize this is poor design.

I'm using these tables for a asp.net MVC web app

Comment: Why do you need to set the value for AccrualMonth? If at all possible I would fix the spelling of that column. It seems to me that you don't need or want this value here anyway. But if you really do then why bother with MERGE? Just update Employee and set every row. You certainly don't want to add new employees here. No idea what you expect to happen on a delete though...

Comment: Use a view that retrieves the current value from AccuralMonth and don't store this on Employee. Redundant data will bring concurrency, out-of-date problems and take additional space.

Comment: @SeanLange Accrual month needed to be editable which I can do for each individual users, but I need a way to edit them altogether as I might have several 100 employees

Comment: That doesn't really explain what you are trying to do. it seems like you want to edit every row in the employee table? I think you need to explain a lot more what your goal is here.

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry for my poor explaination. Yes I am trying to edit every row for the Column `AccuralMonth` But I need this to be accessible  for a user on my web app, hence the way I am going about trying to acheive this

Comment: So why use a MERGE? Just Update Employee set AccrualMotnh = xxx. No magic, just update the entire table.

Comment: Again sorry if it's a stupid question but could I set employee AccuralMonth to whatever value is in `AccuralMonth` column from the `AccuralMonth` table